# Using RegEx with Rules to compare email addresses

Tags: 7, rules

I have a client content type with an email address and when a user creates an account I want to verify the users email address with the email address of the client content type to make sure that the user is an employee of the client and if so let them create an account.

My question is, can I make a rule which uses Regular expressions to compare the domain name of the two email fields?

Thanks

Kieran

Comment: What do you have available in your Drupal site (at the time an account gets created) to know which nodes of your client content type to consider for this validation. Just a wild guess: to create an account, the user enters an eMail ID, and the only thing in common to find a possible match with "a" client node that has that very same eMail Id stored as a value in one of its fields. Or to make things tougher: what follows after the @ sign for both eMail IDs must match. Just a guess, can you clarify to avoid this guessing? Also, why the need for the "RegEx"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use access rules which is built into core drupal.

Go to "/admin/user/rules" and add a new rule, for example `%@domain.com`, this will allow anyone to register who has that specific domain.

Comment: Yeah I can't use that method because there a many clients all with different @domains.com

Comment: How many you need? we are currently using 19 for our company intranet, you start with a deny any rule and follow by allow for any domain you require

Comment: We could have potentially into the 100s.  The other feature of this is that we 1: allow them to create accounts, but also 2: assign them to the specific client based on the @domain name too. So the client buys 10 licences.  Then a user creates an account, it should check that they are using the correct domain, hence the domain check, and then assigns them to that client using one of the licences.  I've done all the licence work using the rules module, but I need to do the authentication on the domain.

Comment: Ahh ok, my answer will unlikely be suitable

Comment: Can anyone else give me any ideas?

Comment: That's a D6 feature. This is a D7 question.